# Dropzone max file only one and remove the second file

Tags: dropzone

I just use my code like this

```
Dropzone.options.attachkyc = {
            maxFiles: 1,
            accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            done();
            },
            init: function() {
                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                    alert("No more files please!");
                });
            },
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function(file) {
                var name = file.name;        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: host+'upload/unfile',
                    data: "id="+name,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
                var _ref;
                return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;   

                //console.log();
            }
        };
```

When i upload second file is show alert "No more files please!", well is working taht file not uploaded, but my problem is, that second file i'm add it still show on my dropzone. My question is how i'm remove second file automaticly after i show the alert??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to remove max file extended file you just have to use `maxfilesexceeded` method of dropzone

```
    init: function() {
         myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                this.removeFile(file);
            });
    },
```

or you can also used one other method too

```
  init: function() {
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {

                if (myDropzone.files.length === 1) {
                    alert("You can Select upto 1 Pictures for Venue Profile.", "error");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                }

            });
 },
```

Comment: the first solution is better. Tq :)

Comment: if i have 100 files i will get 99 alerts

Comment: Is there any way to stop propagation .on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) { ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finaly sovle my problem.
on at

```
 init: function() {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
            });
        },
```

i change it into like this

```
init: function() {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
                this.removeFile(file);
            });
        },
```

is work perfectly i want.

Comment: if you have overflowing by many files, for example 100 files when 1 is allowed you will get 99 alerts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to keep the newly added file and remove the first file that was added you can do something like what is below:

```js
 init: function() {
   myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
     this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
  });
 },
```

You could obviously update the index of  `this.files` to access other files in the array as well.